# How to reset a remote GitHub branch via GitHub API or Octokit?

Tags: github, github-api, octokit.net

I am having a specific situation, when I need to programmatically hard-reset a GitHub branch (basically, delete all commits in the branch). I can only use Octokit, or GitHub API, not git cli. But I can't see corresponding endpoints in API or methods in Octokit to reset remote branches. Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea whether there are any such APIs, but the Git-protocol-level equivalent of `git reset` is `git push`. That may require a forced push (or force-with-lease) in some cases, and that may require permissions on GitHub; the permission rules are entirely up to GitHub.

Comment: @torek there is really nothing to "push". I am writing an API client, which has no storage, therefore there is no cloned repository, and not even git cli installed.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether there are commits to send or not: the push protocol operation consists of the usual negotiation, followed by sending any objects if needed (in this case no objects are needed), followed by a request: *set this reference name <insert ref name> to hash ID <insert hash ID>*. That request *is* a `git reset`.

Comment: Note that it is literally impossible to delete *all* commits in any branch, because any branch name is simply a ref-name of the form `refs/head/<branch>` that contains the hash ID of some valid, existing commit. The commits that are *in* or *on* that branch are that specific commit, plus all reachable previous commits. Usually, when someone says "remove all the commits" they mean "remove some of the commits, namely those that are *only* reachable from this name". GitHub won't actually *remove* the commits, as they never delete any commit: all are always available by hash ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible from github rest api.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).